# CalendarApp.createEvent fails due to permission issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spread sheet, and a script. Whenever something is changes in the sheet, I want a meeting to be created in my calendar. So I write the following script:

```
function onEdit() {
  let meetingTimeMilis = 1000 * 60 * 15;
  let startTime = new Date();
  let endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + meetingTimeMilis);

  let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  eventCal.createEvent('event', startTime, endTime);
}
```

The first time this happens, it asks me to allow this, so I grand all the premonitions, but still I get this error:

```
Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)
    at onEdit(notifyme:84:5)
```

How can I grant this permission too, of bypass this?

Comment: onedit triggers are simple triggers and they cannot perform operations that require permission.  Try changing the name to something other than onedit and create an installable trigger.  If you don't change the name of the function you will wish you did after you finally figure out what the problem is.

Comment: it is not possible for this to be automated? I would like this event to be created automatically when something happens in the sheet

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: Also be aware that onedit trigger only fire when a user makes and edit not when a script or a formula makes and edit

Comment: that's what I want

Comment: What is that?...

Comment: automatic event created on the calendar when the user makes a change in the sheet

Comment: Okay then use an installable trigger instead of a simple trigger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240136/discussion-between-cooper-and-duduarbel).

Answer (score 0):

In theory something as simple as this could work but I think you're going to have to do a little more thinking about the organization of the sheet.  As it is now I just copied your code. But it probably work work as it is now but I would need to know more about your sheet organization.  Or you could learn more about how to create an onEdit function which would be the best way to go.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == 'Your Sheet Name') {
    let meetingTimeMilis = 1000 * 60 * 15;
    let startTime = new Date();
    let endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + meetingTimeMilis);
    let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
    eventCal.createEvent('event', startTime, endTime);
  }
}

function createtrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```